# Docker error : No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a raspberry pi and I have installed dockers in it. I have made a python script to read gpio status in it. So when I run the below command

```
sudo docker run -it --device /dev/gpiomem app-image
```

It runs perfectly and shows the gpio status. Now I have created a `docker-compose.yml` file as I want to deploy this `app.py` to the swarm cluster which I have created.

Below is the content of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        image: app-image
        deploy:
            mode: global
        restart: always
        privileged: true
```

When I start the deployment using `sudo docker stack deploy` command, the image is deployed but it gives error:

```
No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root
```

So it says that it do not have access to `/dev/mem`, but this is very strange when I am using `device`, why the service do not have access. It also says trying running as root which I think all the containers are in root already. I also tried giving the full permissions to the file by including the command `chmod 777 /dev/gpiomem` in the code but it still shows this error.

My main question is that when it runs normally using `docker run..` command why it is showing error in `docker-compose` file when deploying using `sudo docker stack deploy`.? How to resolve this issue.?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adding devices, capabilities, and using privileged mode are not supported in swarm mode. Those options in the yml file exist for using `docker-compose` instead of `docker stack deploy`. You can track the progress on getting these features added to swarm mode in [github issue #24862](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24862).

Since all you need to do is access a device, you may have luck adding the file for the device as a volume, but that's a shot in the dark:

```
volumes:
- /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem
```

Comment: No. It doesn't seem to be working with this approach.

Comment: @user272727 the part of my answer that said this isn't supported didn't work for you?

Comment: I tried specifying `/dev/gpiomem` as `volumes` didnt worked.?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [docker-compose devices](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#devices)

> Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with
>   a (version 3) Compose file.

The devices option is ignored in swarm. You can use `privileged: true` which will give access to all devices.

Comment: What other options I can use.?

Comment: @User272727 you can user privileged option. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Comment: Thank you. So I only need to add `privileged: true` and it will have access to `dev/gpiomem` and lets say I also want `/dev/ttyusb0`. It will also be available.?

Comment: I added the `privileged: true` option in the docker comose file but it still shows the same error. I have edited the docker-compose contents in the question. Pls have a look at it.

Comment: Just when you run your container add --privileged and then your container gets access to all devices, e.g.:
docker run -it --rm --privileged containername:containertag /bin/bash