# Raspberry Pi + Python + Docker - No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root! error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to dockerize a python image to use on a raspberry pi.

This image should be used with docker-compose.

I build the image using:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.6

ENV READTHEDOCS=True

RUN pip install -r /app/confs/requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

RUN groupadd -g 997 gpio

CMD ["/app/start.sh"]
```

Build is ok

Now, this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    my_app:
        image: 192.168.12.2:5000/app_image
        restart: always
        container_name: app
        environment:
            - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
        devices:
            - /dev/gpiomem
            - /dev/vchiq
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - /opt/vc:/opt/vc 
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
```

So i put privileged: true to use all the host devices.

But when i up the docker-compose i always get `RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!` when trying to access to a gpio, but with privileged i should have no problems at all...

Comment: Did you try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441737/docker-error-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root)?

Comment: yes, there is no solution in there, my docker-compose file is the same

Comment: I have found [alpine requires dmidecode in order to use /dev/mem](https://forums.docker.com/t/dev-mem-no-such-file-or-directory-in-ubuntu-linux-14-04-container/28403/2). I don't know what OS contains in `arm32v7/python:3.6` image, but it might work.